# How to run namespaced function onclick and on windows.resize

Tags: jquery, namespaces

I have this function which collapses/expands items in a footer when clicking the header. It works as intended. However, I need to namespace the function, and I can't make it work.

Existing function:

```
var footerHeader = jQuery('.footer-heading');
var footerColumn = jQuery('.footer-heading + .footerlinks');
var cachedWidth = jQuery('body').prop('clientWidth');

var collapseFooter = function(el, ev) {
  // Collapse footer at specified break point
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)').matches) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    jQuery(el).next('ul').slideToggle();
    jQuery(el).toggleClass('open');
  } else {
    jQuery(el).next('ul').show();
  }
};

footerHeader.click(function(e) {
  collapseFooter(this, e);
});

//On resize, wait and remove redundant footer styling
var it;
window.onresize = function() {
  clearTimeout(it);
  it = setTimeout(function() {
    var newWidth = jQuery('body').prop('clientWidth');
    if (newWidth !== cachedWidth) {
      footerHeader.removeClass('open');
      footerColumn.removeAttr('style');
      cachedWidth = newWidth;
    }
  }, 200);
};
```

This is the namespaced version I have made so far:

```
var globalFooter = {
  footerColumn: jQuery('.footer-heading + .footerlinks'),
  cachedWidth: jQuery('body').prop('clientWidth'),

  collapseFooter: function (el, ev) {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)').matches) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      jQuery(el).next('ul').slideToggle();
      jQuery(el).toggleClass('open');
    } else {
      jQuery(el).next('ul').show();
    }
  }
}
jQuery('.footer-heading').on('click', globalFooter.collapseFooter(this, ev));
```

I can't make it work: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: ev is not defined"`. If I remove `"ev"` it still won't work.

Html:

```
<h3 class="footer-heading">Heading</h3>
<ul class="footerlinks" role="menu">
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/h6ahy244/9/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're providing arguments to the function you need to wrap it in another anonymous function:

```
jQuery('.footer-heading').on('click', function(e) {
  globalFooter.collapseFooter(this, e);
});
```